# Django middleware process_template_response method not being called

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the following middleware class:

```
class CommonContextMiddleware:
    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        # Get the context and top videos
        context = response.context_data

        ...

        # Add most_recent and most_viewed to the context...
        context['most_recent'] = top_videos['most_recent'][:3]
        context['most_viewed'] = top_videos['most_viewed'][:3]

        # ...then continue rendering
        return response
```

However, no matter what I put in the function, it's never being called. I presumed that this method would be called for every single template response generated, am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume when you're talking about "template response", you are actually returning a [`TemplateResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/template-response/#django.template.response.TemplateResponse) from your Django view?

This isn't really the best place for this sort of thing. If you just want to add variables into every template context, the best place to do it is in a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

Comment: I just read this answer as I manually replaced every HttpResponse(t.render(c)) with a TemplateResponse(...) I knew there was an easier way. Thanks! By the way, in a context processor, if two variables have the same name (returned from the processor and one set in the context), which one wins?

Comment: It's quite strange that render() with template specified does not returns TemplateResponse. Especially strange because built-in 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' returns it. So I need both middleware and template context processor to make sure variables are injected. Strange. Template context processor isolates template variable dicts from each another, which is non-flexible (however may be more error prone).